# just want to ask if my declaration is correct in my android application

Tags: java, android

I just want to ask if I have set the right value in the `int` result because whenever I run the application my `textview` wont output the product of `ans*ans2`.

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first);
EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second);
String temp = et1.getText().toString();
String temp2 = et2.getText().toString();
int ans = Integer.parseInt(temp);
int ans2 = Integer.parseInt(temp);
int result = ans * ans2;

tv2.setText("" + result);
```

Comment: Are you getting some exception in logcat?

Comment: Does it output anything? Also, should ans2 be initialized with temp2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that problem is related with line

```
int ans2 = Integer.parseInt(temp);
```

where you are parsing value from `temp` instead of `temp2` so try changing it to

```
int ans2 = Integer.parseInt(temp2);
```

Comment: thank you so much i didnt notice that the other temp is not temp2 :D

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work for you.

```
tv1.setText(String.format("%d", result));
```

Comment: Or `tv1.setText(Integer.toString(result));`

Answer (score 0):

tv1.setText(int) refers to a resource id - like R.string.myText

tv1.setText(String) is what you're expecting to call, with Java autoboxing the int to a String.

try:

`tv1.setText(""+result)`

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first);
EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second);
String temp = et1.getText().toString();
String temp2 = et2.getText().toString();
int ans = Integer.parseInt(temp);
int ans2 = Integer.parseInt(temp2 );
int result = ans * ans2;

tv2.setText("" + result);
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and tell me how your answer differers from mine?

Comment: you are converting and assign same  variable temp

Comment: int ans2 = Integer.parseInt(temp2 ); instead of int ans2 = Integer.parseInt(temp );

Comment: Check it once again, especially last line. BTW normally if you agree with some already posted answer you upvote it, not duplicate it :/

Comment: where is the use of temp2 ?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18479177/1393766) last word in last line `int ans2 = Integer.parseInt(temp2);`